# Sign in with ajax with devise

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax, json, ruby-on-rails-4, devise

Im using devise and trying to sign in using ajax and json,
Iv managed to sign up, but having problems signing in and keep getting a Completed 401 unauthorized.

I havent created my own session and registration controller.
This is what i have done:
devise.rb

```
config.navigational_formats = ['*/*', :html, :json]
config.http_authenticatable_on_xhr = false
```

js file

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $.ajax({
        url: "http://localhost:3000/users/sign_in",
        beforeSend: function(xhr) {xhr.setRequestHeader('X-CSRF-Token', $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content'))},
        type: "post",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function(data, textStatus){
            alert("signed in!")
        },
        data: {user: {email: 'test_api2@api.api2', password: 'test1234'} }
    })
});
```

also what happens is, it runs the sign in process twice, first /users/sign_in and after i get teh 401 it runs /users/sign_in.js

webrick:

```
Started POST "/users/sign_in" for ::1 at 2015-05-25 21:58:52 +0200
ActiveRecord::SchemaMigration Load (0.1ms)  SELECT "schema_migrations".* FROM "schema_migrations"
Processing by Devise::SessionsController#create as JSON
Parameters: {"user"=>{"email"=>"test_api2@api.api2", "password"=>"[FILTERED]", "remeber_me"=>"1"}}
User Load (0.2ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."email" = ?  ORDER BY "users"."id" ASC LIMIT 1  [["email", "test_api2@api.api2"]]
(0.1ms)  begin transaction
SQL (0.4ms)  UPDATE "users" SET "last_sign_in_at" = ?, "current_sign_in_at" = ?, "sign_in_count" = ?, "updated_at" = ? WHERE "users"."id" = ?  [["last_sign_in_at", "2015-05-25 19:58:43.414475"], ["current_sign_in_at", "2015-05-25 19:58:52.187823"], ["sign_in_count", 10], ["updated_at", "2015-05-25 19:58:52.188801"], ["id", 2]]
(1.0ms)  commit transaction
Completed 201 Created in 98ms (Views: 0.4ms | ActiveRecord: 2.0ms)


Started GET "/posts/?callback=jQuery1102028774832957424223_1432583931952&_=1432583931953" for ::1 at 2015-05-25 21:58:52 +0200
Processing by PostsController#index as JS
Parameters: {"callback"=>"jQuery1102028774832957424223_1432583931952", "_"=>"1432583931953"}
Completed 401 Unauthorized in 1ms


Started GET "/users/sign_in.js" for ::1 at 2015-05-25 21:58:53 +0200
Processing by Devise::SessionsController#new as JS
Rendered devise/shared/_links.html.erb (4.4ms)
Rendered devise/sessions/new.html.erb (18.9ms)
Completed 200 OK in 23ms (Views: 21.4ms | ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)
```

if you take a look at the sign_in_count iv managed to sign in 10 times.

So my question is why is it giving me a 401 and not displaying the content in the posts_controller and how do i keep the user signed in after iv managed to actually signing in and displaying the content?

The same goes for the registration part aswell, after iv managed to sign up a user its not keeping that user signed in.

Thank you for your time and help.

Comment: please show your PostsController

Comment: Here's the posts_controller https://gist.github.com/anonymous/bf8d1853a5d651872f93